# ClientToScreen() is causing mysterious problems, and I cannot figure out why

Tags: c++

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    initPos.x = LOWORD(lParam);
    initPos.y = HIWORD(lParam);
    break;

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        POINT realPos;
        RECT clientRect;
        int rSect = 0;

        GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRect);

        realPos.x = (int)(short) LOWORD(lParam);
        realPos.y = (int)(short) HIWORD(lParam);

        ClientToScreen(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&clientRect.left));
        ClientToScreen(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&clientRect.right));

        if(wParam == MK_LBUTTON)
        {
            if(!rSect)
            {
                MoveWindow(hWnd, clientRect.left + (realPos.x - initPos.x), clientRect.top + (realPos.y - initPos.y), width, height, TRUE);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

This is a basic snippet of my program that allows my custom window to be dragged around the screen. It works perfect, and I am content with it.

But when I innocently tried to convert realPos and initPos coordinates to screen positions, the window started glitching out every time I dragged it, source code here:

```
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    initPos.x = LOWORD(lParam);
    initPos.y = HIWORD(lParam);
            ClientToScreen(hWnd, &initPos);
    break;

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        POINT realPos;
        RECT clientRect;
        int rSect = 0;

        GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRect);

        realPos.x = (int)(short) LOWORD(lParam);
        realPos.y = (int)(short) HIWORD(lParam);

        ClientToScreen(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&clientRect.left));
        ClientToScreen(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&clientRect.right));
        ClientToScreen(hWnd, &realPos);

        if(wParam == MK_LBUTTON)
        {
            if(!rSect)
            {
                MoveWindow(hWnd, clientRect.left + (realPos.x - initPos.x), clientRect.top + (realPos.y - initPos.y), width, height, TRUE);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

The initPos and realPos should be relative to eachother, as long as they are both relative to the same grid, whether it be a client area or the screen in general. Can anybody tell me why this, then, isn't working? I feel like I'm missing something blatantly obvious...

Comment: Your initPos is being converted at each mouse move message, so it is getting over-converted. Stepping through with the debugger should have revealed this quickly.

Comment: Excuse me, that was my error. I intended to type the initPos conversion to take place within the LBUTTONDOWN event, which produces the error I was intending. The window begins moving rampantly around the screen, for what reason I cannot predict.

Comment: Note also that since you are moving the window, the client to screen conversion keeps changing. Work out the math.

Comment: Have you ever seen something and decided that you're definitely wrong, but could not determine why? That is precisely how I feel about this, hence the reason I asked this question. May thee bless thy with the wisdom and knowledge of thee?

Comment: Nobody shares their wisdom and knowledge better than Raymond Chen. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/

Comment: Step through the code. Suppose the mouse goes down at screen coordinates 100,100. You move the mouse to 100,110. The delta-x is 0 and the delta-y is +10. So the window moves 10 pixels down. So far so good. Then the mouse moves to 110,110. The delta-x is +10 and the delta-y is *still* +10, so you move the mouse 10 pixels to the right *and 10 more pixels down* for a total vertical motion of +20. That's what I meant by working out the math. Just run the algorithm in your head. (A side complication is that your algorithm doesn't work on Arabic or Hebrew systems.)